# Visual Studio 2010: Close All But Selected

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

When I have a bunch of tabs open, the "close all but this" option is very useful. There are times that I'd like to keep 2 or 3 windows open. Is there a way to multi-select the tabs I want and "close all but selected"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the [Productivity Power Tools extenstion](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/) which allows you to 'Pin' pages on the editor frame, among other awesome features.

> •Pinned tabs
>
> Allows you to pin tabs to keep them always visible and available.

Then there is the option to "Close all but pinned"

That should do exactly what your trying to accomplish.

Comment: I actually just installed the Power Tools extension a few minutes ago. Your suggestion is in fact exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: It's interesting that the option doesn't appear if there aren't any tabs pinned. I think it would be better design to have the option disabled rather than hidden. I've never pinned a tab and therefore never seen the option. (I've used Power Tools on other machines.)

Comment: @JonCrowell I suppose you'd have to ask the tools team, I never noticed that to be honest.

Answer (score 6):

From the File, Edit, View menu: Window > Windows…
[image]